# Google Visualization API - error calling method on NPObject

Tags: javascript, flash, google-visualization

I've  been playing with the visualization API aka dynamic charts and I've found that the example at http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html does not really work on localhost. That is, `Error calling method on NPObject` is thrown when a event is clicked (points `A` and `B` in the example aforementioned). I suppose that is a security issue on the server end (Google's flash base).

There's no API key, authentication or anything similar required - as far as I know. What am I missing?

Thanks

**Update:**
The very same example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gT5GB/ Localhost seems not to be the issue, it's the non-google domain I guess.

Since that jsFiddle code is hosted on a domain, the note at the very bottom of the documentation should not apply:

> Because of Flash security settings,
>   this (and all Flash-based
>   visualizations) might not work
>   correctly when accessed from a file
>   location in the browser (e.g.,
>   file:///c:/webhost/myhost/myviz.html)
>   rather than from a web server URL
>   (e.g.,
>   http://www.myhost.com/myviz.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today and have solved it. I was *not* using localhost anywhere, I was hosted on a proper domain, and I too was receiving the NPObject error when clicking on the legends. I was also just using the example directly from http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

The cause was that Google's example uses https://www.google.com/jsapi (note the HTTPS), whereas my site was over plain HTTP. I'm not that familiar with Flash, but I suspect it has similar rules for secure/non-secure as it does for crossdomain requests.

Changing Google's example to use http://www.google.com/jsapi solved the pr

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a limitation related to security in Flash. It's covered here: [Flash - HTTP requests won't work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026488/flash-http-requests-wont-work-on-localhost)

So your best bet is to host this somewhere (it can be a server in the same machine).

Comment: I do have both 3rd party remote server and a localhost server and none does pass the flash security requirements. Nor does the jsFiddle example I've posted.